# fill zero value from function result with case statement

Tags: oracle

i have this query in oracle :

```
WITH LOANS_PRINCIPAL
  AS
  (SELECT 
    MASKAN_RATE.RATE,
    HRS.FN_GETREMIND_BY_DATE(PERSON_DOCK.ID,'2016/01/01') AS PRINCIPAL_DOCK
  FROM
     HRS.TBCONTINUES_PERSON_DOCK PERSON_DOCK
  LEFT JOIN HRS.TBMASKAN_REPAY_CATEGORY MASKAN_REPAY_CAT
  ON MASKAN_REPAY_CAT.ID = PERSON_DOCK.DOCK_REQUEST_DETAIL_ID
  LEFT JOIN HRS.TBFACILITY_MASKAN_RATE MASKAN_RATE
  ON MASKAN_RATE.ID = MASKAN_REPAY_CAT.FACILITY_MASKAN_RATE_ID
  LEFT JOIN HRS.TBFACILITY_MASKAN FACILITY_MASKAN
  ON FACILITY_MASKAN.ID = MASKAN_RATE.FACILITY_MASKAN_ID  
  LEFT JOIN HRS.TBPERSONNEL STAFF
  ON STAFF.ID=FACILITY_MASKAN.PERSONNEL_ID
  WHERE FACILITY_MASKAN.STATE_CODE = 7
  AND STAFF.NO=95801
  AND FACILITY_MASKAN.MASKAN_FACILITY_TYPE_CODE = 4 
  AND PERSON_DOCK.IS_CANCELED_CODE = 2 
  AND PERSON_DOCK.CANCEL_DATE IS NULL
  AND MASKAN_REPAY_CAT.FACILITY_DOCK_TYPE_CODE = 1
  AND FACILITY_MASKAN.FAMILY_ID IS NULL)
  SELECT *
  FROM LOANS_PRINCIPAL
  PIVOT (SUM (PRINCIPAL_DOCK)
  FOR RATE in (4,7,12,13,14,16,10))
```

and result is :

(null)  245221991   97611272    (null)  (null)  (null)  (null)

i need to fill this null value with zero ,prefer fill with case statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `SELECT *` (line 4 from the bottom), write

```
SELECT case when "4" is null then 0 else "4" end as "4",
       case when "7" is null then 0 else "7" end as "7",
... (etc.)
```

In most cases it is not a good idea to use column names in double-quotes (and therefore it is not a good idea to use numbers as column names, since the only way you can do that is by double-quoting them). Rather, it is better to add aliases in the PIVOT clause:

```
... for rate in (4 as rt_4, 7 as rt_7, ....)
```

and then

```
SELECT case when rt_4 is null then 0 else rt_4 end as rt_4, ....
```

It is also unclear why you want to use CASE expressions, when COALESCE does the same thing and is more concise. (So does NVL but perhaps you prefer to use SQL standard constructs; NVL is proprietary Oracle.)

```
SELECT coalesce (rt_4, 0) as rt_4, ...
```

Comment: thank you , this is very helpful for me , CASE expressions is just an idea and not necessary for this problem , i used NVL but dosnot work